# how to do branching logic with regular expressions (specifically, drop 'w' unless followed by a vowel)

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am new to regular expressions and I am trying to implement the metaphone algorithm in vb.net. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone

The algorithm has lots of steps to replace characters depending on certain conditions. (ex. replace w unless followed by a vowel). Is there a way to handle branching logic using regular expressions?

I tried

```
 output = Regex.Replace(input, "w[^aeiou]", "")
```

but this removed the characters after the w too. input=wewl --> output=we (the goal is wel)

I could loop through the characters in the string to solve this problem, but I want to try to do this properly/most efficiently instead of just cranking out baggy code.

Comment: FYI to anyone (now that I better understand Regex), the "|" symbol also handles 'branching logic' for regular expressions. Regex.isMatch("foo"|"bar") returns true for "foo" and "bar"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example could be solved by using

```
 output = Regex.Replace(input, "w([^aeiou])", "$1")
```

I can't tell you if that's the most efficient way, but looking at the Wikipedia page of the replacements, working like this should work.

**Explanation**: the round brackets define a group and the backreferences $1-$9 allow you to use the partial match in the replacement. You can get more information about backreferences on http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: what does the $1 mean? Is it a variable that holds the character after w? It seems like the $1 is a "submatch" i.e. a variable http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#submatches

Answer (score 2):

The reason it is replacing the w as well as the vowel is that replace will replace the entire match and your regular expression is matching the vowel as well.

What you want to use instead is negative lookahead, this should match the w followed by a vowel but will not consume the vowel and thereby not include it in your match and replace. So try a regex like `w(?![aeiou])`

In this regex the `(?!` is the negative lookahead. Here is a great site with details: [Regex Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)